# Which framework is preferable of JavaScript to work with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, frameworks

As we know we have JavaScript frameworks like [Dojo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) and some more others.

Which is best to use with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For business and other Web applications [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/) with [Ext.Net](http://www.ext.net/) wrapper is a great UI JavaScript framework.

Comment: is it contain all commonly used javascript function used in programming...

Comment: It has a lot. http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/

Comment: wow its really nice.... i am changing my selection of answer to u... ok... thanks a lot...

Comment: Take an attention, that Ext.Net is a .NET wrapper for ExtJS library and includes a license for it. It is not free, but it's a bargain.

Answer (score 4):

**jQuery** would top the list of [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) libraries used by even many users of Stack Overflow.

**[YUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library)** is another option to use with [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET).

**Additional Info:**

Comparison chart of all the available JavaScript libraries:

http://blog.creonfx.com/javascript/mootools-vs-jquery-vs-prototype-vs-yui-vs-dojo-comparison-revised

Comment: does jquery contain all datetime related funtions and all other commonly used function of javascript.... i thought Jquery contain mainly design realted issues.

Comment: no it does not, but you can always add another library.

Comment: please tell me library which contain commonly used funtions of javascript (not only design)

Comment: @Dot Net Developer have you used dojo?

Comment: no i haven't used dojo but i heard lot about it

Comment: It depends upon ur requirement if you want a lightweight one go with jquery it does everything for you...

Comment: one thing i want to ask about jquery.... is jquery contain all commonly used javascript function (i heard jquery only contain functions related to design)

Comment: Which javascript function you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery. In ASP.NET MVC, there are documented versions that help with [InteliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense).

You could also use ASP.NET [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) which goes great with WebForms.

In the end, it's up to personal preference.

Comment: i want framework which contain all commonly usefull javascript function used in programming.

Comment: All javascript can be used with any javascript library. you aren't locked in.

Answer (score 1):

**Best** can be a subjective answer and depend on your needs. There are many frameworks currently available and the most popular ones (as I see it) are;

- **jQuery**
- ASP.NET Ajax
- Prototype
- MooTools

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Net provides html tags so that you can cleanly seperate the UI from business logic by providing additional events class like DirectEventArgs.